# Norm in homogeneous Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm having doubts on the definition of the norm in the space $H_0^2$ defined over the (rectangular) domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ as follows
$$
H_0^2(\Omega) = \left\{ v \in L^2(\Omega): v = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2} = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega \right\}
$$

The definition of the norm on this space is given as
$$
\left\|v\right\|_{H_0^2(\Omega)} = \left(\sum_{i = 0}^2 \left\|D^i v\right\|^2\right)^{1/2}
$$

Now, according to my logic, in expanded form said norm would be
$$
\left\|v\right\|_{H_0^2(\Omega)} = \left( \left\|v\right\|^2 + \left\|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}\right\|^2 + \left\| \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_2^2} + 2\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}\right\|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$

If it's not too much trouble, I'd appreciate someone confirming that this is correct, or knock me over the head if it's not :)

Thank you in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Why "homogeneous" Sobolev space? In my limited experience, homogeneous Sobolev spaces are a different thing. Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct, the norm of $Du$, $D^2u$, etc, takes the norm of all individual entries (partial derivatives). So
$$
\|v\|_{H^2}^2 = \|v\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_1^2}\|_{L^2}^2 +\|\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_2^2}\|_{L^2}^2 ,
$$
which is usually written with multi-indices as
$$
\|v\|_{H^2}^2 = \sum_{|\alpha|\le 2} \|D^\alpha v\|_{L^2}^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking that perhaps this is the correct form but was unsure how the notation goes.